# Expressing in interval notation

Tags: inequality, notation

> Solve the inequality $$\frac{2x-3}{x+4} \leq 0$$ Give your answer in interval notation.

$$(-4,3/2] \cup [3/2, \infty)$$

Am I correct?

Comment: What is the $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x-3}{x+4}$$?

Comment: Could you include your work that got you to that answer?

Comment: Checking some values in the interval you suggest was not an option because?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2x-3}{x+4}\leq0\iff$

$[(x+4>0)\wedge(2x-3\leq0)]\vee[(x+4<0)\wedge(2x-3\geq0)]\iff$

$[(x>-4)\wedge(x\leq1.5)]\vee[(x<-4)\wedge(x\geq1.5)]\iff$

$(-4<x\leq1.5)\vee\text{false}\iff$

$-4<x\leq1.5$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** take a good look at the following plot of the graph of $f (x) := \dfrac{2x-3}{x+4}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Note that your proposed interval
\begin{align*}
\left(\left.-4,3/2\right]\right.\cup\left[\left.3/2,\infty\right)\right.=\left(-4,\infty\right)
\end{align*}
is not the correct solution, since e.g. $2\in \left(-4,\infty\right)$, but $\left.\frac{2x-3}{x+4}\right|_{x=2}=\frac{1}{6}>0$

> **Range check:** At first we check the range of definition of the inequality.
>
> - We observe the inequality is defined for all real values as long as the denominator of $\frac{2x-3}{x+4}$ is not equal $0$. We conclude the inequality is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4\}$.

Next  we want to determine the set  of  $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4\}$ where the inequality is true. In order to do so, we multiply with the denominator $x+4$.

We have  to respect that multiplication of an inquality with a positive quantity *preserves* the inequality sign, while multiplication with a negative quantity *inverts* the inequality sign. So, we consider two  cases:

> **Case: $x+4>0$**
>
> In case $x+4>0$ or equivalently $x>-4$ we  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2x-3}{x+4} &\leq 0\\
> 2x-3 &\leq 0\cdot (x+4)\\
> 2x-3 &\leq 0\\
> 2x&\leq 3\\
> x&\leq \frac{3}{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We see, the inequality is valid, if $-4< x\leq \frac{3}{2}$ resp.      in interval notation
>   \begin{align*}
> x\in(-4,3/2]
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Case: $x+4<0$**
>
> In case $x+4<0$ or equivalently $x<-4$ we  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2x-3}{x+4} &\leq 0\\
> 2x-3 &\geq 0\cdot (x+4)\\
> 2x-3 &\geq 0\\
> 2x&\geq 3\\
> x&\geq \frac{3}{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We see, the inequality is never  valid in this case, since there is no $x$ with $x<-4$ and at the same time $x\geq \frac{3}{2}$.

So, only the first case provides solutions for the inequality.

> **Conclusion:**  The inequality is true for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-4\}$ if and only if
>   \begin{align*}
> x\in(-4,3/2]
> \end{align*}